# Align two Tables side by side - Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, html, table

I need to align two tables side by side. My code is here:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" renderAs="pdf" standardController="csclm__Agreement__c" extensions="csclmcb.ClausesController,el_bundledOfferDocumentVFController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
    <head>
        <!-- Stylesheets -->
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.csclmcb__slds, '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css')}" />
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.csclmcb__PDFDocumentStyle}" />
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.csclmcb__PDFstyle, 'PDFstyle.css')}" />
        <style type="text/css">
            @page {
            size: A4;
            margin: 6mm;
            /* padding-top: 4mm; */
            }
            
            body {
            font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';
            }
            
            font {
            font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS' !important;
            }
            
            /*table {
            min-width: 50px;
            }*/
            
            .font-color-white {
            color:white !important;
            }
            
            .font-color-green {
            color:#6fc142 !important;
            }
            
            /*.custom-table-width{
            min-width: 50px;
            }*/
            
            div.footer {
            display: block;
            padding: 5px;
            position: running(footer);
            }
            
            .inlineTable {
            display: inline-block;
            }
            
        </style>   
    </head>
    
    <body style="margin: 10px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial Unicode MS, Sans-Serif; font-size:12px; margin-right: 70px; margin-left: 20px;"> 
        <div style="margin-left: 45px; text-align:center;">  
            <apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bundleElpedisonLogo)}"/>
        </div>
        <apex:repeat value="{!sections}" var="section">
            <div class="section section{!section.csclm__Level__c}">
                <p class="subsection{!section.csclm__Level__c}">
                    {!section.csclm__Numbering__c}
                    {!section.csclm__Section_Name__c}
                </p>
                <apex:repeat value="{!section.csclm__Transactional_Clauses__r}" var="clause">
                    <div class="clause clause{!clause.csclm__Level__c}">
                        <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!SUBSTITUTE(clause.csclm__Final_Rich_Text__c, 'Arial', 'Arial Unicode MS')}"/>
                    </div>
                </apex:repeat>
            </div>
        </apex:repeat>
        
        <div style="margin-left: 50px;" > 
 
        <table style="border: 0.5px solid black;"  width="30%" class="inlineTable"> 
            <tr>
                <td style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS; text-align:center; vertical-align:top; font-size:12px;">
                    ΜΕΤΡΗΤΗΣ ΗΛΕΚΤΡΙΚΗΣ ΕΝΕΡΓΕΙΑΣ
                </td>
                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; font-size:12px;">
                    Αριθμός παροχής 
                    <br/>ηλεκτρικής ενέργειας: 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; font-size:12px;">
                    ΑΦΜ: 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; font-size:12px;">
                    Ονοματεπώνυμο: 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; font-size:12px;">
                    Υπογραφή: 
                </td>
            </tr> 
        </table>
        
        <table style="border: 0.5px solid black; margin-right: 10px; " width="45%" class="inlineTable"> 
            <tr>
                <td style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS; text-align:center; vertical-align:top; font-size:12px;">
                    ΜΕΤΡΗΤΗΣ ΦΥΣΙΚΟΥ ΑΕΡΙΟΥ
                </td>
                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; font-size:12px;">
                    ΗΚΑΣΠ: 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; font-size:12px;">
                    ΑΦΜ: 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; font-size:12px;">
                    Ονοματεπώνυμο: 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; font-size:12px;">
                    Υπογραφή: 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
</apex>
```

Need to align the two tables side by side but I cannot make it.

The best try is this. Can you help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in the past by putting the tables in a parent table similar to the following...

```
<table width="75%">
<tr>
    <td width="30%" valign="top">
    <table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>ΜΕΤΡΗΤΗΣ ΗΛΕΚΤΡΙΚΗΣ ΕΝΕΡΓΕΙΑΣ</td>
    </tr>
    ...
    </table>
    </td>

    <td width="45%" valign="top">
    <table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>ΜΕΤΡΗΤΗΣ ΦΥΣΙΚΟΥ ΑΕΡΙΟΥ</td>
    </tr>
    ...
    </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```